# Label tag not visible

Tags: html, css

Hey so recently I was creating navbar which has this code in html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Page title</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"></link>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
                <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e8f9edfb9f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
                <nav>
                                <h1>&nbsp;<a href="css.html" class="title">Logo</a></h1>
                                      <span class="menu-btn">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
      <label for="check">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
                                      </span>
                                <div class="nav-links">
                                                <a href="#"class="active">Item 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <a href="#">Item 2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <a href="#">Item 3</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <a href="#">Item 4</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </div>
                </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the CSS code

```
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
nav {
                background: black;
                color: white;
                height: 76px !important;
                line-height: 76px;
                color: white;
}
a {
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-btn{
                display: none;
}
@media(max-width: 600px){
                .nav-links{
                                display: none;
                }
                .menu-btn{
                                display: inline;
                }
}
@media(min-width: 600px){
                nav {
                                display: flex;
                                justify-content: space-between;
                }
                .nav-links a {
                                transition: .2s ease-in-out;
                                font-size: 20px;
                                padding: 7px 13px;
                }
                .nav-links a:hover, .nav-links .active{
                                background: white;
                                color: black;
                                border-radius: 12px;
                }
}
```

And the problem is that the label is not visible.
Please tell me something fast.
And yes now you are gonna say that I have made it display none so in the media queries is says display none.
And please don't copy my code.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: `And please don't copy my code`?

Comment: "*Please tell me something fast.*" Please see [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: "*And please don't copy my code*" Contributions here are released under an irrevocable license under Creative Commons, which does permits sharing and modifications of code posted here. Unfortunately your inclusion of this statement does not affect that license. [More info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321291/269970)

Comment: Ask a question well is the beginning of solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is wrapped in a span with the class name `menu-btn`.

but in CSS in `menu-btn` rule set have `display:none;`.

Try removing `display:none` in `menu-btn`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    height: 76px !important;
    line-height: 76px;
    color: white;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-btn {
   
}

@media(max-width: 600px) {
    .nav-links {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-btn {
        display: inline;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 600px) {
    nav {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .nav-links a {
        transition: .2s ease-in-out;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 7px 13px;
    }

    .nav-links a:hover,
    .nav-links .active {
        background: white;
        color: black;
        border-radius: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e8f9edfb9f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <h1>&nbsp;<a href="css.html" class="title">Logo</a></h1>
        <span class="menu-btn">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check">
            <label for="check" style="width:30px;">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
        </span>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <a href="#" class="active">Item 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#">Item 2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#">Item 3</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#">Item 4</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is written in media queries display: inline;